# XML nodes not appearing as children of parent

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'm really having trouble on something that I think should be fairly easy to accomplish.

I have an Excel file that is read into a dataset (called "ds" in my program). The file contains part data that needs to be loaded into a source XML file with the following format (and sample data):

```
<dl:Data>
  <dl:Location>Site01</dl:Location>
  <dl:LogisticsEvent>
    <dl:DateTime>01-JUL-2015 12:00:00 PM</dl:DateTime>
    <dl:AssemblyItem>
      <dl:ProductName>Test Part1</dl:ProductName>
      <dl:ProductNumber>998741</dl:ProductNumber>
      <dl:ProductDash>050</dl:ProductDash>
      <dl:SerialNumber>LX2247</dl:SerialNumber>
      <dl:ProductRevision>R</dl:ProductRevision>
    </dl:AssemblyItem>
    <dl:Activity>Stat Change</dl:Activity>
    <dl:Condition>Good</dl:Condition>
    <dl:Usage>Production</dl:Usage>
  </dl:LogisticsEvent>
</dl:Data>
```

I loop through the excel data and load it into a new dataset (called "ds2" in my program), write it to XML, and then an XMLDocument.

The problem I'm having is that when I view the XML, the data in the *AssemblyItem* tag is not appearing as a child node of the *LogisticsEvent* tag and the data in that tag is not appearing as a child of the *Data* tag. Basically, the *Assembly* tag & everything else in the *LogisticsEvent* tag appear as their own parent nodes (instead as in the sample above).

Here is the code I used to loop through and create the XML:

```
    Dim dsRow As Integer = 0
    Dim gridRow As Integer = 0


    For Each record In ds.Tables(0).Rows

        ds2.Tables(4).Rows.Add()
        ds2.Tables(4).Rows(dsRow).Item("ProductName") = ds.Tables(0).Rows(gridRow).Item("ProductName").ToString
        ds2.Tables(4).Rows(dsRow).Item("ProductNumber") = ds.Tables(0).Rows(gridRow).Item("ProductNumber").ToString
        ds2.Tables(4).Rows(dsRow).Item("ProductDash") = ds.Tables(0).Rows(gridRow).Item("ProductDash").ToString
        ds2.Tables(4).Rows(dsRow).Item("SerialNumber") = ds.Tables(0).Rows(gridRow).Item("SerialNumber").ToString
        ds2.Tables(4).Rows(dsRow).Item("ProductRevision") = ds.Tables(0).Rows(gridRow).Item("ProductRevision").ToString

        ds2.Tables(3).Rows.Add()
        ds2.Tables(3).Rows(dsRow).Item("Activity") = ds.Tables(0).Rows(gridRow).Item("Activity").ToString
        ds2.Tables(3).Rows(dsRow).Item("Condition") = ds.Tables(0).Rows(gridRow).Item("Condition").ToString
        ds2.Tables(3).Rows(dsRow).Item("Usage") = ds.Tables(0).Rows(gridRow).Item("Usage").ToString

        dsRow += 1
        gridRow += 1

    Next

    ds2.AcceptChanges()
    ds2.WriteXml(filePathFull)

    Dim xDoc As New XmlDocument
    Dim schemaLocation As XmlAttribute = Nothing
    Dim schemaString As String = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    Dim schemaValue As String = "http://www.tgin.org/trident/7143706-001 7143706-001RevA.xsd"


    xDoc.Load(filePathFull)
    schemaLocation = xDoc.CreateAttribute("xsi", "schemaLocation", schemaString)
    schemaLocation.Value = schemaValue
    xDoc.DocumentElement.SetAttributeNode(schemaLocation)
    xDoc.Save(filePathFull)
```

On the first loop, the data appears correctly in the XML. It's on the subsequent loops that XML gets messed up. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```css
        Dim newRow As DataRow = Nothing
        For Each record As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows

            newRow = ds2.Tables(4).Rows.Add()
            DataRow.Item("ProductName") = record.Item("ProductName").ToString
            DataRow.Item("ProductNumber") = record.Item("ProductNumber").ToString
            DataRow.Item("ProductDash") = record.Item("ProductDash").ToString
            DataRow.Item("SerialNumber") = record.Item("SerialNumber").ToString
            DataRow.Item("ProductRevision") = record.Item("ProductRevision").ToString

            newRow = ds2.Tables(3).Rows.Add()
            newRow.Item("Activity") = record.Item("Activity").ToString
            newRow.Item("Condition") = record.Item("Condition").ToString
            newRow.Item("Usage") = record.Item("Usage").ToString

        Next

​
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work. The output displays the first set of data as null and then each node following as its own parent.

Comment: Does excel data start in row 1?  Do you have headers on the rows in excel?  You connection string needs to be change so the headers (HDR = YES/NO)are set correctly.  See following webpage : http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/

Comment: I have headers in my file; therefore the data starts at row 2. Here is my connection string: `conn = New OleDbConnection _ ("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _ "Data Source = '" & xlFile & "';" & _ "Extended Properties = ""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";")`

Is there any other code you would like to see that may help?

Comment: Try without schema and see if anything changes.  Also try without running AcceptChanges().

Comment: When you mean "without schema" are you referring to when i write the XML as in `ds2.WriteXML(fileName, XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema)`? If so, I did try that and that did not change anything. I also commented everything after `Dim xDoc`... and that did not change anything. I did more checking and found on some of the MSDN pages that it looks like the problem is something simple like table nesting. I tried to set the nested property of ds2.relations to "True" but that didn't change anything

Comment: In the end I couldn't find anything to solve this. I recreated the datatables and set the datarelations between the parents and children using `dataset.relations.add(relationName, parentTableColumn, childTablecolumn`. I then set the nested property of the relation to true, hid the key columns and the final XML appeared as it should. I will mark you response as the answer as it prompted me to take a different approach to solving my problem (plus i learned some more things regarding XML in vb.net). Thanks for the help!